# Extensible Python markdown processor

Tags: python, markdown

I'm looking for a Python module that can process [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) but where I can disable any of the features (and thus use a custom subset of the markup, while leaving the rest un-processed).

The [Markdown](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown) module seems extensible, but it I don't see how can I disable certain rules.

The [Markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) module has something they call "extras", but it's all built in, and the code looks horribly constructed and not easily exstensible.

To be clear, my question here is, does such a module exist, or am I better off implementing my own (or forking one of the above modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no-one has responded, we've ended up implementing a subset of Markdown ourselves. None of the markdown engines seem to be extensible enough.

Comment: If you are allowed to do so, it might be worthwhile to link to your work so that others may benefit!

Comment: Yes I would also definitely like to see that!